# Can we develop our own code metrics through Roslyn Analyzers?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, roslyn-code-analysis

Visual Studio 2019 and the FxCop Analyzers provide the user with some code metrics.
(See https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-generate-code-metrics-data?view=vs-2019 )

As FxCop uses roslyn I thought their functionality could be recreated. I would like to extend them through my own roslyn analyzer. It would be great to be able to use the same visual studio window and functionalities. If it is not possible I would have to write a command line roslyn tool with other output functionalities.
I did not find anything about it online, so if its possible to develope own metrics please give me a hint. If it is currently not supported by self developed roslyn analyzers consider this to be a feature request^^

Thanks for any answers